# Why are nested associated type paths considered ambiguous?

Tags: rust

Why are nested associated type paths considered ambiguous?

```rust
fn flatten<I>(iter: I) -> Option<I::Item::Item>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: IntoIterator,
{
    None
}
```

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
 --> src/lib.rs:1:34
  |
1 | fn flatten<I>(iter: I) -> Option<I::Item::Item>
  |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<<I as Iterator>::Item as Trait>::Item`
```

Shouldn't the compiler be able to resolve the path without fully-qualified syntax? There is only one type I could be referring to, so I don't see why it is ambiguous. Is this a limitation of the compiler or is it intended behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a compiler limitation: [Nested associated type projection is overly conservative #38078](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38078). There's a bit of hope that [chalk](https://github.com/rust-lang/chalk) will improve the situation, but there's no guarantee that it will.